# Spring BeanCreationException: Unexpected exception during bean creation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a notification library (written in Spring Boot, gradle, Java) which has a Service class (an interface) and an Implementation class (which extends the Service class and overrides the methods).

Service interface:

```
public interface NotificationService {
    void sendNotification(String title, String message, List<String> ids);
```

Implementation class:

```
@Component
public class NotificationServiceImpl implements NotificationService {
    private String notificationServiceURL;

    public NotificationServiceImpl(@Value("${notificationService.url}") String notificationServiceURL) {
        this.notificationServiceURL = notificationServiceURL;
    }

    public void sendNotification(String title, String message, List<String> employeeIds) {
        // Some functionality
    }
}
```

Application.yaml

```
notificationService:
  url: "someURL"
```

I have packaged this library as a JAR and imported in some project which is also Spring boot project.

Now, in the main class, I added Component Scan for the path where the imported library classes are:

```
@ComponentScan({"com.abchealth.xyz.red", "com.abchealth.xyz.red.service", "com.abchealth.xyz.red.service.serviceImpl"})
public class SecondProject {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SecondProject.class, args);
    }
}
```

Then in one of the inner classes, I created an object of NotificationService

```
@Slf4j
@Component
@StepScope
public class SomeInnerClass implements Tasklet {

    @Autowired
    NotificationService notificationService;

    // some code
```

When I run the application, it gives me this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'notificationServiceImpl' defined in URL [jar:file:/Users/usera/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.abchealth.xyz.red/notification-lib/1.0.0-12/f973790603b7c261b2f6a693e83ca3e8f3f021de/notification-lib-1.0.0-12-scan.jar!/com/abchealth/xyz/red/service/serviceImpl/NotificationServiceImpl.class]: Unexpected exception during bean creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'notificationService.url' in value "${notificationService.url}"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:529) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
```

Note: If I test this directly in Notification library by creating an object of NotificationService, it works just fine! The issue is when it is being imported in other project.

Answer (score 1):

You need add `notificationService.url` property to your SecondProject's application.yml

Comment: Is there no way it can read directly from notification lib, instead of adding again to Second Project?

Comment: you can use the annotation @PropertySource on the class NotificationServiceImpl to indicate which property file it should use to retrieve the properties needed.